# Compression Algorithms output files larger than the originals. Why?

Tags: arcpy, gdal, compression, file-size

I'm currently attempting to write a script that will compress a few hundred .tif files.  I've tried two approaches, first I wrote a script in Python using CopyRaster_management() function and the second I wrote with GDAL using the gdal_translate() function.  However, in both cases, the files outputted from the script are larger than the originals and I do not know why.  The files in question are .tif scans that are uncompressed from .zip files.  The only case that works is when I run a JPEG compression in the ArcGIS environment which drastically reduces the size by ~80%.  Any ideas why this is?

My Python script is as follows:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r“Z:\ScannedImages\LZWCompressInput”
rasList = arcpy.ListRasters()
outWs = r“Z:\ScannedImages\LZWCompressOutput”

arcpy.env.compression = “LZW″
for ras in rasList:
  arcpy.CopyRaster_management(ras, os.path.join(outWs, ras))
```

As for gdal, I run a command like this:

```
gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=LZW" infile.tif outfile.tif
```

Comment: I've tried pretty much everything each program allows as compression algorithms, for GDAL: JPEG, LZW, Packbits, Deflate, CCITT and for Arc: LZW, LZ77, JPEG, JPEG2000 and PackBits.  As for compression on the original files I'm little unsure, I looked at the metadata and it says the files are uncompressed, however I extracted .tif files from a few .zip files.

Comment: Compression does not mean the file will be smaller, in some cases (RLE for example) the file can be larger than the original. I'm surprised that JPEG2000 (what compression ratio) doesn't work for you, as a lossy file type you should be able to get down to 5-10% of the file size so long as you don't expect terrific images. How are you applying the compression, and is it 'sticking'? i.e. are you sure the outputs are compressed? When you refer to the original file size are you stating the size of the zip file or the unpacked file?

Comment: Sorry folks, when I say "original files" I'm referring to the unpacked file.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson When I run it in Arc I alter the compression environment variable and in GDAL I just state what compression I'll use as a parameter in the gdal_translate command.  According to gdalinfo, the compression sticks, and you are right in that a JPEG compression reduces the image size drastically.

Comment: Edit that into your question please, it's very hard to follow python without formatting. By compression environment variable you mean the arcpy.env. setting don't you. What data type are they? Are they RGB/RGBA UChar, 32bit float... not all compression methods are supported for all pixel formats: read more http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000020000000

Comment: Sorry, I was having issues with SE's comment formatting.  I just recently discovered they are a mix of 1 bit and 8 bit RGB scans.  I'm assuming I'll need different compression methods for each bit depth, however I tried that approach and JPEG compression is still the only method that gives me the results I need.

Comment: @ChrisW, you're totally right.  I posted my scripts in my question.  Do you happen to remember those .tif compression tools you mentioned?

Comment: Cleaned up my comment trail a bit as much has been addressed now. The only window/dialog I know for sure is the have it in a map, right-click, export method. That's not really a tool, so I don't know it can be called in a script but you could test with that method. Everything else it's an environment setting parameter, and it seems like you've addressed that in your script. I was about to link to the same help page Michael has (which links to others), and he raises a good point about supported methods. But LZW should be good for anything. JPG methods throw away data, so no surprise they work.

Comment: Have you checked whether the input tif files are already compressed? You said you verify the output compression using gdal-info/ Have you used gdal info to verify compression (or lack thereof) on the input rather than relying on the metadata? Another good check is whether the files extracted from the zip archive are similar in size to the zipped file size.

Comment: Ok so after doing some digging I found out that some of the files are already compressed with LZW and some aren't, and that the files I was testing my code with were these already compressed files.  Sigh... at least now the mystery is solved.

Comment: I would encourage you to write up an answer to your own question on this one to help anyone who encounters the same mystery in the future.